# how to pass list when redirect to another controller in mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, redirect

This is my search action I get the output value with query and I want to pass this value to another action `AddCurrency`, but after redirect the value became null although it have value before redirect please help me what is the error here:

```
//the output after redirect became null
public ActionResult SearchCurrency(string Word)
{
    List<Currency> Output = (from Cur in db.Currencies.ToList()
                             where Word.All(s => Cur.currencyname.Contains(s))
                             select Cur).ToList();

    return RedirectToAction("AddCurrency",Output);
}

//  this is my AddCurrency Action 
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult AddCurrency(List<Currency> Output =null)
{
    if (Output !=null)
    {
        ViewBag.L = from cur in Output where cur.CurrencyProperties == "L"  select cur;
        ViewBag.T = from cur in Output where cur.CurrencyProperties == "T" select cur;
        ViewBag.B = from cur in Output where cur.CurrencyProperties == "B" select cur;
        ViewBag.Count = Output.Count();

        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: You cannot pass a collection to a GET method. And in your case there is no need to - just pass `string Word` to the `AddCurrency()` method and do you query there.

Comment: thank you for your quick answer already redirect with value

Comment: What do you mean _already redirect with value_?

Comment: i mean the value of ( word) became not null as you say i passed the word and make query in other action worked fine thank you but if the method is POST it will accept collection ?

Comment: Yes, assuming you view is generated correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save data in TempData and use it in the redirected action method.